# ¿Cual es la mejor forma de hacer un select de contrato actual y contrato anterior de un empleado en una misma fila?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, oracle-11g

Buenas, estoy programando consultas en Oracle 11g y PostgreSQL 9.4, y me han solicitado realizar una consulta cuya salida se muestra en la imagen siguiente.

[image: Salida de consulta]

Employee_ID pertenece a la tabla de empleados; Current_Contract_ID y Previous_Contract_Id son el mismo campo Contract_id de la tabla contratos,
me piden que programe un query donde se muestre el contrato actual y el contrato anterior de un empleado en una misma fila.

¿Cual es la mejor manera de programar dicha consulta?

Así es como se tienen las tablas
[image: tablas]

Comment: Puedes incluir en tu pregunta una muestra de los datos en las `empleados` y `contratos` para que podamos entender de donde vienen los resultados deseados? Y explicarnos la logica de como se determina el contrato actual y el anterior? Esos son detalles muy importantes para entender bien el contexto.

Comment: ok, ando en ello, por cierto hago una corrección, en donde dice 400 en realidad es 500

Comment: ya subí unas tablas de ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El query más limpio que pude pensar a estas horas es este, si no hay contrato previo el query debe regresar `NULL` en ese campo; se puede especificar un valor `DEFAULT` para los registros no encontrados pero tendría que ser del tipo `DATE` pero también se puede usar `COALESCE` y un `CAST` para cambiar ese `NULL` a otro texto de ser necesario.

```
SELECT DISTINCT EMPLOYEE_ID, CITY_ID, NOMBRE, APELLIDO,
LAG(CONTRACT_ID, 0 ) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID ORDER BY contratos.START_DATE ASC),
LAG(CONTRACT_ID, 1 ) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID ORDER BY contratos.START_DATE ASC)
FROM empleados
LEFT JOIN ciudades ON empleados.CITY_ID = ciudades.CITY_ID
LEFT JOIN contratos ON empleados.EMPLOYEE_ID = contratos.EMPLOYEE_ID 
ORDER BY contratos.START_DATE
```

El único inconveniente es que `DISTINCT` se debe aplicar a `EMPLOYEE_ID` y por tanto el campo no sale en orden puedes seleccionar el orden correcto si a este query le rodeas con otro query:

```
SELECT CITY_ID, NOMBRE, (orden correcto)... FROM (...TODO EL QUERY ANTERIOR...) alias
```

Espero te ayude.

Answer (score 1):

## Funciones tipo windowing

Existen funciones de tipo windowing para hacer estas tareas: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html

La función **lag** te da el renglón de arriba y **lead** el renglón de abajo. Si solo quieres mostrar el último renglón (con el de arriba) hay que meter un select dentro de otro para filtrar al final. Va el ejemplo para que se entienda:

```
select * from (
  select empleados.*, ciudades.ciudad, 
        contratos.contract_id, 
        contratos.start_date,
        contratos.end_date,
        lag(contratos.contract_id) over (partition by empleados.employee_id order by contratos.start_date) as contrato_anterior,
        lag(contratos.start_date) over (partition by empleados.employee_id order by contratos.start_date) as contrato_anterior_start_date,
        lag(contratos.end_date) over (partition by empleados.employee_id order by contratos.start_date) as contrato_anterior_end_date
    from contratos 
      inner join empleados on contratos.employee_id=empleados.employee_id
      left join ciudades on ciudades.city_id = empleados.city_id
  ) select_base_con_todo_junto
  where end_date is null;
```

### versión completa

Puse una versión completa con los insert y create table en: http://rextester.com/EPM24088

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que la lógica que determina el contrato actual y anterior es el valor de la columna `start_date`. Si ese es el caso, usando `row_number()` y agregaciones condicionales, se puede sacar la información de esta manera:

```
with ct as (
  select employee_id,
         max(case when rnk = 1 then contract_id end) as current_contract_id,
         max(case when rnk = 2 then contract_id end) as previous_contract_id
    from (select contract_id,
                 employee_id,
                 row_number() over (partition by employee_id order by start_date desc) as rnk
            from contratos) c
   group by employee_id
)
select c.ciudad,
       e.employee_id,
       e.nombre,
       e.apellido,
       ct.current_contract_id,
       ct.previous_contract_id
  from empleados e
  join ciudades c
    on c.city_id = e.city_id
  join ct
    on ct.employee_id = e.employee_id
```

La consulta debería funcionar en ambos Oracle y PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CITIES.CITYID, A.EMPLOYEEID, EMPLOYEES.NOMBRE AS NAME, EMPLOYEES.LASTNAME, A.CURRENTCONTRACTID, B.PREVIOUSCONTRACTID
FROM (
  (
    (
      SELECT  EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEEID, MAX(CONTRACTID) AS CURRENTCONTRACTID FROM 
      EMPLOYEES INNER JOIN CONTRACTS ON EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEEID = CONTRACTS.EMPLOYEEID
      GROUP BY EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEEID
      )  AS A 
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT EMPLOYEEID, MAX(PREVIOUSCONTRACTIDG) AS PREVIOUSCONTRACTID FROM
      (
       SELECT C.EMPLOYEEID, C.PREVIOUSCONTRACTIDG FROM
          ( 
            SELECT  EMPLOYEEID, CONTRACTID AS PREVIOUSCONTRACTIDG FROM CONTRACTS ) AS C
          INNER JOIN
          (
            SELECT  EMPLOYEEID, MAX(CONTRACTID) AS PREVIOUSCONTRACTIDG FROM CONTRACTS GROUP BY EMPLOYEEID
           ) AS D
          ON C.EMPLOYEEID = D.EMPLOYEEID 
          WHERE C.PREVIOUSCONTRACTIDG < D.PREVIOUSCONTRACTIDG
          )
          GROUP BY EMPLOYEEID
        )  AS B ON A.EMPLOYEEID = B.EMPLOYEEID
      ) 
   INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES ON A.EMPLOYEEID = EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEEID
 ) 
INNER JOIN CITIES ON EMPLOYEES.CITYID = CITIES.CITYID
```

En vez del campo 'NAME' en la tabla 'EMPLOYEE' utilicé 'NOMBRE', por lo que le puse un alias al campo.